# Magento2 : Get Product Collection With Stock Data

Tags: magento2, inventory

Currently, we require to load product's stock data from stockregistry which increases database connection if working with foreach loop for product collection.

I want to reduce it anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leftjoin "`cataloginventory_stock_item`" table with the product collection.

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                // addAttributeToFilter() function can be used for filteration of attributes
                // addFieldToFilter() function can be used for filteration of fields
                ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->joinTable(
                    'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    ['*'], // you can specify specific columns here
                    null,
                    'left'
                );
```